# How to stop Windows Explorer from taking up 70 percent of CPU?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, virus, cpu-usage

When I start up my computer (Windows 7) I always run Task Manager to kill any buggy programs if they occur. About a week ago, when I did so, I noticed that `Explorer.exe` was taking up 70 percent of the CPU according to Task Manager.

This is DEFINITELY a new development, and I assumed it was a virus of some sort. So I scanned with AVG, then JRT and then even proceeded to run SpyHunter on it. 
None of them picked up anything.

I searched online and the latest results I'm getting from Google are from 2012 or 2011. Not very relevant. I've resorted to just killing `Explorer.exe` and using the Task Manager's "new task" feature to start all of my programs. But it's getting irritating, especially as my computer is primarily for gaming and coding  and both take up more than 30 percent of my CPU.

Now when I run a game, either it's a stuttery crawl (even with `Explorer.exe` canned) or I have to wait about an hour to get it to run smoothly. I would REALLY like to solve this, though I don't have very much space on my hard drive, so any low-space solutions would really be appreciated.

Thanks,

~Keelen

Comment: provide a xperf trace of the CPU usgae: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD

Comment: Co-incidentally I have a Windows 7 workstation at work which has much the same issue. Nothing I tried so far helped so I am with you on this one and see if someone has an idea.

Comment: If you have to "kill buggy programs" each time you start your computer, you have more serious problems, of which Explorer using lots of CPU is likely just another symptom.

Answer (score 0):

Use a system optimizer like System Mechanic and also try not to open lots of programs and dont mess your desktop and taskbar. Also you can end its process and then try to re run it then the problem will go for some minutes :D ..
But seriously try to

- use a system optimizer app. it is a need for windows systems (Best choice is System Mechanic)
- also try to update your windows
- and update your graphic card's driver.

These 3 things can rev up your pc.
Also this answer from an old question can help: https://superuser.com/a/297835/396608